# Spanning a Record Over Multiple Rows in WPF Toolkit's DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is it possible to style WPF Toolkit's DataGrid so a data record can span multiple rows. [Example screen shot](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/windows-forms/grid/multiple-rows-and-columns-per-record) from a commercial control.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible with the toolkit DataGrid or GridView for a ListView, no.

**However** you may have luck with your own implementation, as I recently discovered you can use `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewheaderrowpresenter.aspx)), set the `Columns` property to the columns you want: that will give you a header row.

Then you can use `GridViewRowPresenter` ([MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewrowpresenter.aspx)), attach it to the same `Columns` collection and voila, your columns in the rows and header will be linked (resize the header, the columns change).

See here for a good example:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752313.aspx

**In order to get the stacked effect**, you could create a `ListView` or `ListBox`, and for each item you'd output a vertically-stacked pair of `GridViewRowPresenter` controls, each bound to a separate columns collection.  Then in your own custom header (just above the control) you'd do the same thing with a pair of `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter` controls.

You could then add any other bits you'd like as well, for example the text/label that they have in your example screenshot.

No reason why this shouldn't work.  It's not a pre-built solution but is possible with clean coding, it's not a hack, and you have complete control over how it looks and works!  Adding sorting and so on is fairly easy too, MSDN has an example for that too.

Hope that helps - any more questions on the details of this please add a comment here!

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though the control in that screenshot is creating the illusion of row-span by dividing the cells in every column to the right of the picture into multiple rows. Perhaps you could achieve the row-span effect you are looking for in the same way.

```
<tk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />
        <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Photo">
            <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">FirstName</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">LastName</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </tk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>
```