# Wpf C# Datagrid row columns spanning multiple rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is it possible to create a DataGrid looking something like this is Wpf?

I have a column with important information to display, but the text is too long to display it all horizontally. Therfore i need to display it in a vertical fashion.

[image: DataGrid]

Cheers!

Daan

Comment: See this question, it may answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181244/spanning-a-record-over-multiple-rows-in-wpf-toolkits-datagrid